# Creating a view between two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, view

I'm having trouble creating a view between two tables, as I'm quite new to SQL. I need to create a view which will show which employees have carried out work as consultants within the past 14 days. The result of the view should also display this kind of layout:

```
14 day consultancy report 
-----------------------------------------------
Employee Helvin Paul worked for 6 hours for factory ltd chargeable £351
```

The two tables I assume you will need to join together are the `Employee` table and also the `Consultancy` table. I will show both below as I have them in a text file from when I was creating these tables:

```sql
create table Funtom_employee 
(
    emp_ID      Number(3)  primary key,    
    Emp_firstname   varchar2(50) not null,
    Emp_surname varchar2(50),
    Emp_department  Number(2) constraint FK_funtom_dept references 
    funtom_department,
    emp_street  varchar2(50),
    emp_town    varchar2(50),
    emp_district    varchar2(50),
    Emp_grade   Number(3) default 4 constraint chk_emp_grd check (Emp_grade between 1 and 9),
    Emp_site    varchar2(30) default 'LONDON',

    constraint  FK_funtom_grade funtom_grade references funtom_department
);

create table Funtom_consultancy
(
    consultancy_ID  Number(3) primary key,
    Consultancy_emp Number(3) constraint cns_emp references funtom_employee,
    Consultancy_hours   Number(4,2) constraint consultancy_check check (Consultancy_hours > 1),
    Consultancy_client  Number(3) references funtom_customer,
    Consultancy_date    DATE,
    Consultancy_activity    Number(3) references funtom_activity
);
```

Thanks to anyone that can help with this create view and for your time

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: Yes sorry I am using MySQL

Comment: Okay, my answer should work well with MySQL, though I tried to make it as standardized as possible

Answer (score 0):

A view can be created using the `CREATE VIEW` [statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp). An example based on your data is listed below.

```
CREATE VIEW consultancy_report as 
select
    Funtom_employee.Emp_firstname,
    Funtom_consultancy.Consultancy_date,
from
    Funtom_employee
    join Funtom_consultancy
        on Funtom_employee.emp_id = Funtom_consultancy.Consultancy_emp
```

You can add whatever other fields you need from either table in the select clause of the query. I've demonstrated one field from both tables.

If you want output explicitly as listed in your sample, you will need to [concatenate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) several fields together as one string. Since this feels like a homework question, I will leave that as an exercise for you.